# Why is there snow in my sunken rooms?

Tags: the-sims-3

So I've been experimenting with sunken rooms (where the house in general is built on a foundation, but some rooms are built lower on ground level with modular stairs making them accessible from the rest of the house).

My house currently has 3 such rooms:

- Living room
- Part of the bedroom
- Study

Unfortunately, given that it appears that there's snow on the floor of 2 of these rooms (bedroom and living room), I'm guessing there's a problem with the ceiling.

Here's how I built the rooms:

1. Place foundation for the room
2. Build the walls
3. *constrainfloorelevation false*
4. Remove foundation
5. Place bottom section of wall
6. Auto-level walls

My roof is basically just a 2nd story that I've surrounded with one of the small walls (not the "waist height" ones).

I've [taken some screenshots](http://www.imgur.com/a/Tu37Y) to help clarify what's going on.

Comment: So you don't have a flat roof from Build mode, just a second story floor?

Comment: That's how it was. I have since replaced it with a flat roof from build mode, but it's not made any improvement